# Fill matrix with value by searching for index and column names in other DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot, index-match

I have a "empty" data frame looking as follows:

```
        6807    6809    5341
126293  nan     nan     nan
126294  nan     nan     nan     
126295  nan     nan     nan
```

The column names give me an `name_id` whereas the index values give me a `file_id`. Now I want to search for the `file_id` and the `name_id` in separate pandas data frames named `pro`, `cont`, and `neutral` which look like this:

```
    file_id name_id
0   126293  7244
1   126293  4978
2   126293  5112
3   126293  6864
```

If I find the `file_id`and `name_id`in the `pro`dataframe I want to fill the empty data frame cell above with `1`, when found in `cont` then `-1` when in `neutral`, then the value entered into the matrix should be `0`. Giving me a result like this, e.g.:

```
        6807    6809    5341
126293  1       -1     0
126294  0       -1     0        
126295  1       -1     1
```

Does someone know how to get this done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can stack your 'empty' df (let's call it `df`) and merge against a combination of `pro`, `con` and `neu`. Then you can re-arrange it back into a 2d shape

Put the votes together into one dataframe:

```
votes = pd.concat([pro.assign(v=1), con.assign(v=-1), neu.assign(v=0)])
votes['name_id'] = votes['name_id'].astype(str) # you may or may not have to do this depending on what type your actual df is, as I have no way of knowing. It should match the type from columns in the empty df
```

`votes` now look like this (made up numbers by me):

```
    file_id name_id v
0   126293  6807    1
1   126293  4978    1
2   126293  5112    1
3   126293  6864    1
0   126295  6809    -1
0   126294  5341    0
```

Now we merge it to a stacked `df` on name_id and file_id:

```
df1  = (df.unstack()
            .reset_index()
            .merge(votes, left_on = ['level_0','level_1'], 
                right_on = [ 'name_id','file_id'], how='left')[['level_0', 'level_1', 'v']]
)
```

`df1` looks like

```
    level_0 level_1 v
0   6807    126293  1.0
1   6807    126294  NaN
2   6807    126295  NaN
3   6809    126293  NaN
4   6809    126294  NaN
5   6809    126295  -1.0
6   5341    126293  NaN
7   5341    126294  0.0
8   5341    126295  NaN
```

Now `unstack` it back

```
df1.set_index(['level_1','level_0']).unstack()
```

output:

```
        v
level_0 5341    6807    6809
level_1         
126293  NaN     1.0     NaN
126294  0.0     NaN     NaN
126295  NaN     NaN    -1.0
```

You get NaNs where you had no votes in either pro con or neu. The votes in those dfs that are for file_id/name_id not originally present in `df` are ignored

Comment: interesting, I was wondering if there was a way to do this using multi level indexing

Comment: @piterbarg Wow, thank you very much! This looks great. One question: When trying to unstack ```df```I get the error message ```KeyError: 'level_0'```. What does this mean?

Comment: @AlexanderHempfing it sounds like there is no column 'level_0' at that point in time so `df1.set_index(['level_1','level_0'])` fails. which is a bit strange. does your `df1` look like the one I showed in the answer?

Answer (score 2):

Here is one approach, use the intersection of `file_id` and `name_id` found in the `pro`, `neutral`, and `cont` `DataFrame` as an index to set the values you want either 1, 0, or -1. I use the Python `set` class to perform the intersection. However, it doesn't index well into the `DataFrame` because it results in a `tuple`.

EDIT: 1/29/2022
I missed an important step in my previous solution. The itertools product needs to be used in order to get all permutations of `df.index` and `df.columns` combinations. See updated code below.

```
from itertools import product

pro_idx = set(product(df.index, df.columns)).intersection(zip(pro['file_id'], pro['name_id']))
neut_idx = set(product(df.index, df.columns)).intersection(zip(neutral['file_id'], neutral['name_id']))
cont_idx = set(product(df.index, df.columns)).intersection(zip(cont['file_id'], cont['name_id']))

if any(pro_idx):
    for f,n in pro_idx:
        df.loc[f,n] = 1
        
if any(neut_idx):
    for f,n in neut_idx:
        df.loc[f,n] = 0
        
if any(cont_idx):
    for f,n in cont_idx:
        df.loc[f,n] = -1
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work with the panda data frames it seems...

Comment: Oh? It worked in my test case. Is it not putting the 1 , 0 or -1? Or is it crashing?

Comment: ```pro_idx = set(zip(df.index, df.columns))```zips ```file_id```and ```name_id```, however, with after ```.intersection(zip(pro['name_id'], pro['file_nr']))```it returns a empty set. Afterwards, it does also not fill 1,0 or -1.

Comment: I see, there was an important step missing in my solution. I have updated the code above. Basically it needed the check all combinations of df.index and df.columns for the intersection to work.